# Search or compare value in the textbox in certain folder or directory(location) and list the log file which have the exact value in it

Tags: vba, excel

[Hi All I am just new in VBA excel macro and trying to create my own macro. the vb mini-program i have will search for specific value(example. 15) in all the log files in certain directory or location. Once the value was found in the log file, the program will list it in list box. my program is functioning. My only problem is, if theres hundreds or thousands of log files in the location, the program will list all log data with value of 1 or 5 including the log data with the exact value 15. the other problem is that the log data with value of 15 will be listed below which is supposed to be on the top or listed at the first found item which have the correct value. Below are my questions.

1. Is it possible that if the program found out the log data with exact value, the program will list it on top or can be listed first?
2. It is more easy also if the output will be  limit . Because if there are thousands or hundreds of file with 1 and 5 , everything will be listed in the list box. is it possible to list only the right log data with value of 15? Kindly see below snapshot and code. I am planning to use this macro also in my work the reason why I am trying to figure it out.

Program:
[image]

```
Private Sub Comfind_Click()

    Dim theString As String
    Dim path As String
    Dim StrFile As String
    Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
    Dim file As TextStream
    Dim line As String
    Dim blnFound As Boolean

    ListLog.Clear
    theString = TextPlate.Text

    path = TextPath.Text
    StrFile = Dir(path & "*.pdms")

    Do While StrFile <> ""
        'Find TheString in the file
        'If found, list log and exit loop

        Set file = fso.OpenTextFile(path & StrFile)
        Do While Not file.AtEndOfLine
            line = file.ReadLine
            If InStr(1, line, theString, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
           ListLog.AddItem StrFile

                Exit Do
            End If

        Loop
        file.Close
        Set file = Nothing
        Set fso = Nothing
        StrFile = Dir()

    Loop
     MsgBox "successfully search log data!!!"    

End Sub
```

Log file:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can narrow it down a bit:

```
Dim arr
Do While Not file.AtEndOfLine
    line = file.ReadLine
    If InStr(1, line, "PLATEKEY", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        arr = Split(line, "PLATEKEY")
        If Trim(arr(1)) = theString Then
            ListLog.AddItem StrFile
            Exit Do
        End If
    End If
Loop
```

Comment: hi your code works . thank you. But i have another question. is it possible also if no result it will pop-up no data log found? I know how Msgbox work but i don't have an idea were to put it . do I need to created another if condition to suit that requirement? Thank you!